# Joining two tables and getting the dept names with condition count of female count greater than count of male

Tags: sql, select

We have two tables called `dept` and `emp`.

`dept` table has 2 columns: `dept_id` and `dept_name`.
`emp` table also has 2 columns: `dept_id` and `Gender`.

I have to get the `dept_name` which has more **female** count than **male**  count.

Comment: Question: What have you tried?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT dept_name FROM
(
   SELECT D.dept_name,
       SUM(CASE WHEN E.Gender = 'Female' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FeMaleCount, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN E.Gender = 'Male' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) MaleCount
   FROM Dept D JOIN EMP E ON E.dept_id = D.dept_id 
   GROUP BY D.dept_name
) X WHERE X.FeMaleCount > X.MaleCount
```

> The CASE expression has two formats:
>
> - The simple CASE expression compares an expression to a set of simple expressions to determine the result.
> - The searched CASE expression evaluates a set of Boolean expressions to determine the result.

You want the searched CASE expression syntax:

```
CASE
     WHEN Boolean_expression THEN result_expression [ ...n ] 
     [ ELSE else_result_expression ] 
END
```

---

As a side note, if performance is an issue you may find that this expression runs more quickly if you rewrite using a JOIN and GROUP BY instead of using a dependent subquery.